# Is there an style property for lines that permit overlapping?

Tags: reactjs, styles, line, layer, mapbox-gl

I have a line layer with the following style:

```
{
    type: 'line',
    'source-layer': 'pluto15v1',
    "layout": {
      "line-round-limit": 1,
      "line-cap": "round",
      "line-miter-limit": 0,
      "line-join": "round"
    },
    "paint": {
        "line-color": [
            "step",
            ["zoom"],
            "hsla(0, 86%, 56%, 0.2)",
            7,
            "hsla(0, 86%, 56%, 0.58)",
            13,
            "hsl(0, 86%, 56%)",
            22,
            "hsla(0, 86%, 56%, 0.29)"
        ],
        "line-width": [
            "interpolate",
            ["linear"],
            ["zoom"],
            9,
            13,
            16,
            22,
            22,
            22
        ],
        "line-opacity": 0.76
    }
  }
```

Originally, with Mapbox v1 it displayed this way

[image]

As you can see the overlapping lines display a more intense red.

Then I upgrate to Mapboxv2, and de lines overlapping disappeared and it displays like everything was only one line.

[image]

Is there any attribute to display like in v1?

The current version of mapbox is 2.8.1, with React 16.12.0